# Is there any method to set up virtual env for running python code in jenkins ubuntu pipeline server?

Tags: python, docker, jenkins-pipeline, virtualenv

i tried so many ways to run my python code but it does not work and i install Docker plugin also but again jenkins tell me that docker not found

wrote this pipeline :
pipeline {
agent any

```
stages {
    stage('Setup Virtual Environment') {
        steps {
            // Create a virtual environment named 'venv'
            sh 'python3 -m venv venv'
        }
    }

    

    stage('Run Tests') {
        steps {
            // Activate the virtual environment and run your Python script
            sh '. venv/bin/activate && python test_sign_in.py'
        }
    }
}
```

}

but it give me this error :

- python3 -m venv venv
  The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
  available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
  package using the following command.

  apt install python3.10-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is giving you good advice:

`you need to install the python3-venv package using the following command. apt install python3.10-venv`

This means your base image (e.g. Ubuntu) doesn't have everything you need to setup your venv.

My advice would be to run your steps manually via terminal first, using exactly the same OS you will use in Jenkins, to confirm they work. Then create the same steps in your Jenkins pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do would be to install the `python3-venv` on the host system where Jenkins in installed, then your stages should work.

Or to have a more... portable approach, like scaling or reinstall Jenkins Server.
Install Docker on the host system, make the user running Jenkins part of the Docker group, and then run your stages in a docker container.
With a prepared image for your task or build and use it in the pipeline.
To start, just run the same docker commands in a `sh "docker build..."` as on your local machine.
The Jenkins Docker Plugin can be complicated at the beginning.